# Round datetime to last hour

Tags: php, datetime, rounding

I tried to look for this but I could not find good example of this what im trying to do.

I got datetime values in MySQL database that has to be rounded down when that value is on use.

Example, all these values:

> 2013-04-20 07:14:42
>   2013-04-20 07:19:51
>   2013-04-20 07:37:26
>   2013-04-20 07:46:28
>   2013-04-20 07:59:44

Should be rounded down to:

> 2013-04-20 07:00:00

And

> 2013-04-20 16:25:34

should be:

> 2013-04-20 16:00:00 etc...

PHP code that gets date value:

```
$d = strtotime($row["date"]);
```

So, how its possible to round down datetime value?

Comment: Are does datetimes UTC?

Comment: what about microseconds?

Comment: Function for arbitrarily rounding PHP DateTimes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399274/339440

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this,

```
$date = "2013-04-20 16:25:34"; 
echo date("Y-m-d H:00:00",strtotime($date));
```

**[CodePad Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QnIwaw)**

Comment: Thanks :)
Got it working with this:
$d = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:00:00",strtotime($row["date"])));

Answer (score 24):

If you are using PHP's Carbon DateTime library (which you really should - https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon )

You can achieve it easily using

`Carbon::now()->minute(0)->second(0);`

Comment: what about microseconds?

Comment: Check my answer as i use `startOfHour();`

Answer (score 12):

Since you already have a Unix timestamp `$d`, most efficient way is to use only arithmetic instead of date functions - especially if you're going to loop through a result set.

```
$hourTimestamp = $d - ($d % 3600);
```

Modulo operator gives you the remainder which you subtract from the timestamp to get hour timestamp.

Comment: PHP dates consider timezones while unix timestamps are always in UTC so this won't give the expected result for timezones like India (UTC+5½) or Iran (UTC+3½).

Answer (score 4):

Refering to @Dayson response, this is a better way to round datetime to last hour with Carbon

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2012, 1, 31, 15, 32, 45);
echo $dt->startOfHour();  // 2012-01-31 15:00:00
```

check the *Modifier* section in Carbon [Doc](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff)

Answer (score 3):

In that case a simple `substr` could do:

```
echo substr($date, 0, 13) . ":00:00";
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who follow (much later!): Carbon has an easy way to do this

```
$date = (new Carbon($row['date']))->minute(0)->second(0)->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: what about microseconds?

Comment: Check my answer as i use `startOfHour();`

Answer (score 1):

you can use 
[`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function function to achieve this, simply already change your minutes and second accordling

```
    $date = '2013-04-20 07:14:42';
    $newdate = date('Y-m-d H:00:00', strtotime($date));

    echo $newdate;
```

this will output

```
2013-04-20 07:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

This writes the date to a string by outputting directly `00:00` as minutes and seconds instead of writing `i:s`:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:00:00", $d);
```

---

Or do you need it as unix timestamp? Then cut the minutes and the seconds off (always the last 5 bytes) and replace them by `00:00`.

```
$d = strtotime(substr($row["date"], 0, -5)."00:00"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime()` gives you a Unix timestamp which is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

What if just divided by 3600 seconds (seconds equivalent to 1 hour) and ignore the remainders (the minutes and seconds you do want)?

```
$d = strtotime($row["date"]);
$rounded_d = intval($d / 3600);
$formatted_rounded_d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $rounded_d)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important you use a built-in PHP function for rounding times to take into account the date as well as the time. For example `2020-10-09 23:37:35` needs to become `2020-10-10 00:00:00` when rounding up to nearest hour.

*Round time to nearest hour*:

```php
$time = '2020-10-09 23:37:35';

$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", round(strtotime($time) / 3600) * 3600); // 2020-10-10 00:00:00

$time = '2020-10-09 23:15:35';

$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", round(strtotime($time) / 3600) * 3600); // 2020-10-09 23:00:00
```

*Round time to nearest 20 minute increment*:

```php
$time = '2020-10-09 23:15:35';

$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", ceil(strtotime($time) / (60*20))*(60*20)); // 2020-10-09 23:20:00

$time = '2020-10-09 23:41:35';

$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", ceil(strtotime($time) / (60*20))*(60*20)); // 2020-10-10 00:00:00
```

If you need to round *down to nearest 20 minute increment*, change `ceil` to `floor` e.g

```php
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", floor(strtotime($time) / (60*20))*(60*20)); // 2020-10-09 23:40:00
```

If you need to round time to another minute increment you can simply do:

```php
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", ceil(strtotime($time) / (60*15))*(60*15)); // 2020-10-09 23:45:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use DateTime's `setTime()` method in a function like this.

```php
<?php

/**
 * @param \DateTime $dateTime
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
function roundDownToHour(\DateTime $dateTime)
{
    $dt = $dateTime; // clone

    return $dt->setTime(
        $dateTime->format("H"),
        0,
        0
    );
}

$testDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(9, 59, 59, 1, 30, 2019));
$roundedDownToHour = roundDownToHour(new \DateTime($testDate));

var_dump($testDate); //=> 2019-01-30 9:59:59
var_dump($roundedDownToHour->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")); //=> 2019-01-30 09:00:00
```

Which results to the following.

```php
// the results
string(19) "2019-01-30 09:59:59"
string(19) "2019-01-30 09:00:00"
```