# SQL Counter Select statement on an hourly basis

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, counter

I'm looking to turn my counter into something that can monitor the progress on an hourly basis.

As of now I have a counter that will give me my daily counter, now I want to adapt it to show what the figure is come every hour.

My code is as follows:

```
$Hourly = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Current Built FROM line_detail WHERE station_no=22 AND time(comp_date)>='2014-02-07'");// i need to change it from date to time but to update every hour.
$counter1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Hourly);
print $counter1['Current Built'];
```

what can you suggest i need to do in order to make the changes and get the timer to change and update on an hourly basis?

could i possibly do this by putting it on a loop somewhere?

thanks

Comment: So you want it to show the count up to the last hour in the day? e.g. if the time now is 12:45 PM, you would want a count up until 12:00 PM?

Comment: I don't understand the code.  Can you show some sample data and desired results?  For instance, why are you extracting the time from one field and then comparing the result to a date?

Comment: yes just on an hourly basis for the day so at 00;00 its a fresh start then 01;00 02;00 will all update when there is a refresh, i am going to have this as live information. - comp_date is just a column in the DB i have set up, it stores both date and time to when it was completed

Comment: Try something like `AND time(comp_date) >= " . strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:00:00"), time())` I based that off this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118565/round-datetime-to-last-hour Please note I am unable to test that code presently, so you may need to make some alterations

Comment: thanks @mwrichardson, that near enough sorted me out! this is the code that worked for me in the end  '(date('H', strtotime($bikeBuilt['comp_date'])) == $this_hour)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to solve this with thanks to @mwrichardson

i used what he suggested had a fiddle and came out with

```
(date('H', strtotime($bikeBuilt['comp_date'])) == $this_hour)
```

i ended up putting it into an array and calling this.